# Watch face and user action

Tags: wear-os

Is it possible to add any user action to a watch face application?

I'd like to add a button on a watch face that triggers some logic.

When I deploy the watch face application for the first time, the touch events are routed to the button and I can do fun stuff.

Once the clock goes to sleep, then Google takes over, and all my touches trigger the default google voice search.

I assume that the google voice takes over the whole surface, as a layer, and my button never receives the button pressed events.

Is there a work around like, I can swipe from right-to-left to get an action button?

Is there a way to disable the google voice search from a watch face?

Thanks in advance,

-Jukka

Comment: Generally the word has been from Google that the Watchface features of android Wear 4.4 wasn't really a priority for them. In Android Wear 5.0 Lollipop - there are supposed to be a lot of enhancements. It is expected the 1st week of December 2014. Also not that all users are upgraded, there will be no brand or model of device that isn't upgraded (Google controls upgrades on Wear, unlike phones).